# Display reminder at Bottom of Home Screen

Tags: android, widget

I have a fragment in my application main activity where I get some info from User. I need to display this fragment as a Reminder every 24 hours. I need the reminder to be displayed at bottom of Home Screen..(like reminders in any.do app)

Comment: can you please give a bit more detail? Are you trying to display a notification every 24 hours or just a dialog in the app every 24 hours?

Comment: It is a notification, and should be displayed even if the app is not running, but I need this notification to be displayed at the bottom of Home Screen.

Comment: example: http://i60.tinypic.com/rlyvww.jpg